# When using the node.js vm module, is there a way to limit or even measure how much memory is being used by the vm during runInNewContext()?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to determine if there is a way to limit (or at a minimum, measure) how much memory is being used by a particular `vm.runInNewContext()` call.

*Note: This question is specifically about the node.js `vm` module (I make that point because lots of the searching I've been doing on this topic return references about running node.js in a VM).*